# append method is not working in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple json object and each object have multiple same, For example:
A->
 - A1 
    -A1A
    -A1A
 - A2
    -A2A
    -A2A
 - A3
    -A3A
    -A3A

I have tired to execute in below code but it's not working. Can you please suggest me what is the issue in my code?

```js
subscriptionbarMyData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('subscriptionBarJson'));
$('.total-month-cost-product-header-names').text('').addClass('hidden');
for (var key in subscriptionbarMyData) {
  if (subscriptionbarMyData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var val = subscriptionbarMyData[key];
    $('.total-month-cost-product-header')
      .find('.total-month-cost-product-header-names')
      .removeClass('hidden')
      .addClass('show')
      .text(val.Name + val.ProductPrice);

    var addonvalue = subscriptionbarMyData[key]["Add-on"];
    for (var keyval in addonvalue) {
      if (addonvalue != undefined) {
        var TotalOneCostProduct = $('.total-month-cost-product-items').text('');

        for (var keyval in addonvalue) {
          // var dataValues = addonvalue[keyval].Name;
          $('.total-month-cost-product-header-names')
            .text(addonvalue[keyval].Name)
            .appendTo(TotalOneCostProduct);

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="summary-block">
  <div class="total-month-cost-summary">
    <div class="total-month-cost-product-header">
      <div class="total-month-cost-product-header-names"></div>
      <div class="total-month-cost-product-header-price"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="total-month-cost-product-items">
      <div class="total-month-cost-product-item-names"></div>
      <div class="total-month-cost-product-item-price"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: What happens when you run it? Any errors in the console? Any (wrong) output on screen?

Comment: Can you post an example of "subscriptionbarMyData" object ?

Comment: Actually, I'm able to add append the items into block but i'm not able to remove that.

Comment: @ZiedGUESMI,

“one”: {
 “1”: “data”,
 “2”: “data”,
 “3”: “data”,
“one-one”: {
 “1”: “data”,
 “2”: “data”,
 “3”: “data”,
}

}

Comment: similarly, I'm pushing this json data into div block but the same case i'm not able to remove that based on that object.

Comment: Does your JSON array has keys called "Key" as you have used .hasOwnProperty(key)  what are the keys in your json array?

Comment: I'm fetching the JSON object "one" then i'm appending the data